# Overlaid matlab plots with two different y-axis scales

Tags: matlab, plot, label

I am trying to get MatLab to produce a plot with two y-axes of differing scales. The code I have so far is:

```
    function [h]=YieldvspH1(a)

data1=importdata(a);

data=data1.data;
text=data1.textdata;

yield=data(:,1);
pH=data(:,2);

for i=1:length(pH)
    dates(i,:)=[str2num(text{i,1}(1:2)),str2num(text{i,1}(4:5)),str2num(text{i,1}(7:8))];
    dates2(i,:)=text{i,1};
end

h=figure;

hold on
set(gcf,'PaperPositionMode','auto');

plot1=plot(pH,'linewidth',1.5);
plot2=plot(yield,'m','linewidth',1.5)

h_ax=gca;
h_ax_line=axes('position', get(h_ax, 'position')); % Create a new axes in the same position as the first one, overlaid on top
set(h_ax_line, 'YAxisLocation', 'right'); % Put the new axes' y labels on the right
ylabel(h_ax, 'pH');
ylabel(h_ax_line, 'Yields');
set(gca, 'XTick',1:length(dates), 'XTickLabel',dates2(1:pointsperday:length(dates(:,1)),:),'xlim',[0 length(dates)]);
xlabel('Time');

holdoff
```

However this produces an empty plot with no data and incorrect scales. The data that I read in as the variable a is a csv file with the structure:

17/01/2014 , 40.2 , 5.9

18/01/2014 , 38.6 , 6.2

(one line per day for ~40 days)

The date field is read in as textdata and then converted to numbers. The second field is read in as 'yield' and the third is read in as pH. So the goal is to have pH values on a left side y-axis and the yield values on the right side y-axis, with dates along the x-axis. I'm not terribly experienced with Matlab so please forgive any obvious mistakes!

Any tips would be greatly appreciated!

edit: Ok so thanks to nkjt's answer below I have this function now:

```
function [h] = YieldvspH1(a)

data1 = importdata(a);

data = data1.data;
text = data1.textdata;

yield = data(:,1);
pH = data(:,2);

h=figure

dates = datenum(2014,1,18):1:datenum(2014,2,28);

[ax, h1, h2] = plotyy(dates,yield,dates,pH);

for n = 1:2
  datetick(ax(n),'x','dd/mm');
end
```

Trouble is matlab expects the first argument of the datetick function to be either 'x', 'y' or 'z'. I have tried converting the two axes seperately without the use of a loop but I still end up with one in the dd/mm format and another in a weird format (numbers like 7E5). How can I correct for this?

Cheers

Comment: Will [`plotyy`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/plotyy.html) help you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason that when you define a second axis your plot appears blank is that an "axis" doesn't just have external labels but an internal plotting space as well - it's like putting an extra blank plot over the top of what you've already plotted. This can be fixed by creating the new axes with `'Color','none'`, if you really want to try and do this by hand.

However, as mentioned in comments, you can use `plotyy` instead.  I would combine this with `datetick` for easier plotting against time.

First, define your x-axis values using `datenum`:

```
dates = datenum(2014,1,17):1:datenum(2014,2,25);
```

If you have them as a set of strings in cells you can also convert using `datenum` and giving it the format `'dd/mm/yyyy'`.

```
dates = datenum(text{:,1}, 'dd/mm/yyyy');
```

Second, taking those datenum values as our x-axis values:

```
[ax, h1, h2] =plotyy(dates,yield,dates,pH);
```

You can use `h1` and `h2` as handles to adjust the linewidth, etc. after plotting using `set`.

`ax` contains two handles, one to each axis produced by `plotyy`. We can use these to set the format of the x-axis using `datetick`. The two axes have to be set to the same values otherwise you'll get weird overlapping text, and it seems `datetick` will only handle one axis at a time, hence a loop:

```
for n = 1:2
  datetick(ax(n),'x','dd-mmm');
end
```

`datetick` accepts a wide range of formats. If you want to adjust the exact position of the ticks, change them through `set` first (remember to set both ax(1) and ax(2) to the same values), then call `datetick` with the options `'keepticks','keeplimits'`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Seems to work nicely apart from the datetick part. I keep getting the error message:

`code`
??? Error using ==> datetick (parseinputs)
The axis must be 'x','y', or 'z'.
`code`
I don't think the datetick function can handle having the ax(n) as a argument. I've tried to do them seperatly and can't make that work, any ideas?

Comment: It might be a version difference; try just `datetick('x','dd-mmm')`. In that case it will probably just tackle the current axes, so you may still need to call `datetick` twice, and use `axes` to swap which of the two axes are current.

Comment: Thanks for all your help. I struggled getting it to call `datetick` twice and so ended up doing it once and then using `set(ax(2),'xtick',[]);` to stop the second x-axis from being displayed.